# Is the fight against Genishiro winnable?

Tags: sekiro-shadows-die-twice

The fight at the beginning of the game where, when you lose it, you lose your arm... is it possible to win it?

And if you do, how does the game react to it?

Comment: i won and i thought that the game ends right away and wolf and heir just go and make their own destiny :)

Comment: Would be a pretty funny secret ending. You won the fight that your loss is supposed to start it all? ROLL CREDITS!

Comment: @Fredy31 the Far Cry 4 and 5 have some secret "endings" like that - basically if you refuse to take the action that starts the plot of the game for long enough, the credits just start and the game is over.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, but the only thing that changes is the cutscene after the fight. You get hit by a sneak attack by an unseen foe, and then Genishiro cuts your arm off.

You can see it in action here:

Comment: The shuriken that flies in looks like one of the curved ones that the Nightjar Samurai use. You first encounter them outside Ashina Castle.